# Rails 5.2 Devise Edit via Partial Submitting via Put not Post

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm using a partial to edit just one column of my Devise `User` table and when I hit submit it's defaulting to `put` instead of `post`.

The view looks like this:

```
<h4 class="color-white font-weight-bold responsive-heading">
 Add your code to your profile now!
</h4>
<% if current_user %>
  <%= render partial: "devise/registrations/update_swing_code" %>
<% else %>
  <%= link_to "Create My Free Account", new_user_registration_path, class: "btn btn-yellow" %>
<% end %>
```

With this partial:

```
<% @user = current_user %>

<%= simple_form_for(@user, as: User, :url => update_swing_code_path, :html => { :method => :put }) do |f| %>
  <%= hidden_field_tag(:string_code, id: "hiddenStringCode") %>

  <section class="form-inputs">
    <div class="form-group text-center">
      <input id="field01" type="text" class="form-control display-3 font-typewriter inline-block code-digit inputs" maxlength="1" style="width: 50px; height: 70px; font-size: 2rem" >
      <input id="field02" type="text" class="form-control display-3 font-typewriter inline-block code-digit inputs" maxlength="1" style="width: 50px; height: 70px; font-size: 2rem" >
      <input id="field03" type="text" class="form-control display-3 font-typewriter inline-block code-digit inputs" maxlength="1" style="width: 50px; height: 70px; font-size: 2rem" >
      -
      <input id="field04" type="text" class="form-control display-3 font-typewriter inline-block code-digit inputs" maxlength="1" style="width: 50px; height: 70px; font-size: 2rem" >
      <input id="field05" type="text" class="form-control display-3 font-typewriter inline-block code-digit inputs" maxlength="1" style="width: 50px; height: 70px; font-size: 2rem" >
      <input id="field06" type="text" class="form-control display-3 font-typewriter inline-block code-digit inputs" maxlength="1" style="width: 50px; height: 70px; font-size: 2rem" >
      -
      <input id="field07" type="text" class="form-control display-3 font-typewriter inline-block code-digit inputs" maxlength="1" style="width: 50px; height: 70px; font-size: 2rem" >
      <input id="field08" type="text" class="form-control display-3 font-typewriter inline-block code-digit inputs" maxlength="1" style="width: 50px; height: 70px; font-size: 2rem" >
      <input id="field09" type="text" class="form-control display-3 font-typewriter inline-block code-digit inputs" maxlength="1" style="width: 50px; height: 70px; font-size: 2rem" >
      <input id="field10" type="text" class="form-control display-3 font-typewriter inline-block code-digit inputs" maxlength="1" style="width: 50px; height: 70px; font-size: 2rem" >
    </div>
 </section>

 <div class="text-center">
   <%= f.error_notification %>
 </div>

  <div id="submitButton" class="form-actions mt-3">
    <%= f.button :submit, "Update My Swing Code", class: "btn btn-yellow", controller: "registrations", method: :post %>
  </div>

<% end %>



<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".code-digit").keyup(function () {
        if (this.value.length == this.maxLength) {
          $(this).next('.inputs').focus();
        }
        var swing_code = "";
        swing_code = $("#field01").val() + $("#field02").val() + $("#field03").val() + "-" + $("#field04").val() + $("#field05").val() + $("#field06").val() + "-" + $("#field07").val() + $("#field08").val() + $("#field09").val() + $("#field10").val()
        $("#string_code").val( swing_code );
    });
  });
</script>
```

My `registrations_controller` has this method:

def update_swing_code
    @user = User.find(current_user.id)
    @user.swing_code = params[:swing_code]
    @user.save
    redirect_to user_path(@user)
    flash[:notice] = "Your swing code has been saved!"
  end

And my `routes` have this:

```
  devise_for :users, :controllers => { registrations: 'registrations' }
  resources :users, only: [:show, :index]
  get 'users/show'
  get 'users/index'
  devise_scope :user do
   post "/users/:id/update_swing_code" => "registrations#update_swing_code", as: "update_swing_code"
  end
```

Yet when I hit the submit button (despite the explicit guidance that it use `method: :post`, I still get the red and white screen of death saying:

> No route matches [PUT] "/users/fullswing/update_swing_code"

Can anyone help me figure out how to get this guy to submit?  For such a simple task it's taking waaaaay too long to debug!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's using `PUT` instead of `POST` because in your `simple_form_for` call, your using `html => { :method => :put }`. If you want to use `POST`, you should change your `simple_form_for` to use `html => { :method => :post }` and remove the `method: :post` from your `f.button` call. Do keep in mind, though, that Rails convention is to use `PATCH` to make updates, not `POST`. You shouldn't need to add a HTTP method, though. Rails will infer the method from the instance variable. If it is a new record, Rails will use the `POST` HTTP method and if it's not a new record, Rails will use the `PATCH` HTTP method.

Read about [Resource Routing](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default)